# Error in local storage - NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED - firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, local-storage

I've been working in a web application and I'm using local storage. But for some Firefox users I notice that they're having the following error:

> NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED: Component returned failure code: 0x8052000b
>   (NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED) [nsIDOMStorage.setItem]

when it called the function:

```
function setLocalStorageItem(key, value){ 
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}
```

It's is a way to avoid this error?

Comment: Can those users perform a `getItem`? I expect this error means that Firefox's file-level representation of the `localStorage` data is messed up, due to a browser-level error or a hardware problem (including a sudden power outage, as described in http://askubuntu.com/q/110649/164449).

Comment: Do you happen to know which version of firefox they're running?

Comment: @Xeano Yes, it's the 23 version

Comment: @apsillers yes also the getItem has the same error

Comment: I had this issue with Jira/Confluence. After clearing 'offline website data', removing `storage.sqlite` in my Firefox profile folder, and restarting Firefox, the issue was resolved.

Comment: @Luc : Thank you so much ! The work around is just good for nothing, catching the error is not solving the issue at all ! Removing storage.sqlite did work perfectly ! (here is its path : /home/<user>/.mozilla/firefox/uj78j9ov.default/storage.sqlite

Comment: currently, a user of the web I develop had this error, the error tracker tells me it uses firefox 78 and Linux

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is a browser-level error: you probably didn't do anything wrong to cause this error. The browser (or the the SQLite library it uses) either did something wrong, or the file was left in an invalid state due to a hardware problem.

You can't really prevent this issue, except by joining the Firefox development team and making the browser's storage system more fault-resistant. There doesn't seem to be any way to restore data from this error, so what you'll have to do is detect this error and tell users how to blow away their browser storage according to [this MDN post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FStorage#Storage_location_and_clearing_the_data):

```
try {
    setLocalStorageItem(key, value);
} catch(e) {
    if(e.name == "NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED") {
        showMessageSomehow("Sorry, it looks like your browser storage has been corrupted. Please clear your storage by going to Tools -> Clear Recent History -> Cookies and set time range to 'Everything'. This will remove the corrupted browser storage across all sites.");
    }
}
```

Note that the `catch` block should verify that the error is an `NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED` error. I think my check on `e.name` is correct, but you should verify it for yourself.

Answer (score 66):

After an OS crash files within the Firefox profile folder might be corrupt and lead to non-functional websites (in my case ironically the Firefox marketplace). Here, `webappsstore.sqlite` was affected.

As user @Oli stated over at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110649/how-can-i-stop-firefox-throwing-a-ns-error-file-corrupted-error)

> Firefox stores its HTML5 data in a file called webappsstore.sqlite.
>   That's sitting in your profile directory which lurks somewhere in
>   ~/.mozilla/firefox/....default/ (depending on what your profile is
>   called).
>
> Move that out the way and restart Firefox and everything will come
>   back to life.

More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage

If deleted/moved out of your profile folder, Firefox builds a new, sanitized `webappsstore.sqlite` file. *Worked for me.*
Information on where to find your profile folder can be [accessed here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox).

Comment: Was also `webappsstore.sqlite` on my machine. Used `for i in $(find . -name '*.sqlite'); do echo "$i"; echo "PRAGMA integrity_check;" | sqlite3 -bail "$i"; done` in profile directory to verify no other db was broken

Comment: This worked for me, as some faulty software corrupted some files on my hard drive, with `webappsstore.sqlite` being one of them. Thanks!

Comment: This fixed the issue for me also on macOS. The folder was: `/Users/myusername/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/.....default/`

Comment: the nice developers at mozilla should maybe consider making the system a bit more resilient. If the cache returns a failure, then blow away the cache rather than fail the operation. How many man hours are wasted on us digging up stackoverflow questions to find out the internals of a browser cache so we can manually delete it.

Answer (score 37):

Clearing everything via the Firefox preferences may not fully clear the local storage where the corrupted SQLite file resides.

At this point, you have two options:

- Pop open your console and clear the storage via a Javascript command (hat tip: https://davidjb.com/blog/2017/11/resolving-an-ns_error_file_corrupted-error-in-mozilla-firefox/):

```
localStorage.clear()
sessionStorage.clear()
```

- Use the terminal to delete the corrupted SQLite file and force Firefox to rebuild it.

Steps for macOS users:

1. `cd /Users/myusername/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/.....default/`
2. `rm webappsstore.sqlite`
3. Verify no other files corrupted using this script from [TheConstructor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1266906/theconstructor):

   `for i in $(find . -name '*.sqlite'); do echo "$i"; echo "PRAGMA integrity_check;" | sqlite3 -bail "$i"; done`
4. Restart Firefox and reload the page.

Comment: Just `localStorage.clear()` in the console solved the issue for me.

Comment: I had this issue when using TimeMachine to restore a backup. Afterwards, macOS Firefox would give me problems where localstorage was used. Thanks to the "Steps for macOS users", it's now fixed. Thanks!

Comment: I had this issue with Atlassian - their JavaScript code tried to load something corrupted and cannot get around it otherwise, but this console magic fixed it.

Comment: That's exactly what triggered my problem too... someone should tell them there's this thing called Jira that can help with bug tracking.

Comment: The integrity checked worked well in my case. One addition was to pipe the output to a file then look for DBs which were not OK. In my case it found a corrupted index which can be rebuilt with https://sqlite.org/lang_reindex.html .

Comment: I first ran into this in Atlassian, and then now in LinkedIn.  I am a seasoned web developer and I can't believe doing it through UI (Dev Tools > Storage > all the storages, one by one > delete all) didn't do the job, but this command line one, did it!  Awesome, thank you. <3

Comment: Next time I see Joel Spolsky I will have to thank him for creating SO: It was all worth it for this one answer!

Answer (score 6):

### Firefox on MacOS Big Sur (11.4)

I was living with this problem for over a month, hoping that a new version of Firefox will come and it will be fixed.  I didn't, at least until version <s>89.0.2, July 2021</s> 92.0 Sep 2021, that I am currently on.

## Why is it happening?

As other answers mention, it happens when your machine crashes and Firefox leaves its sqlite storage files in a broken state on disk.  Yes, Mozilla should have been more resilient, but it's not. :(

## What should I do now?

I downloaded and reinstalled Firefox and cleared `~/Library/Firefox` and `~/Library/Mozilla` and they didn't help either.

I have found that you have 3 solutions to try.  Depending on how severe the damaged file is, one of them might work.

---

### Solution 1: Clear localStorage and sessionStorage

Hit F12 (Tools > Browser Tools > Browser Console) and paste

```js
localStorage.clear();sessionStorage.clear()
```

I have a bookmarklet for it solution (as mentioned on the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58294401).)  My bookmarklet is `javascript:localStorage.clear();sessionStorage.clear();` and I hit it every time I was running into a page that not responding and the console (F12) in Firefox was showing this `NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED` error.

However, it is so annoying and this solution isn't working on certain websites (e.g. AWS, or Jira).

---

### Solution 2: Manual deletion of certain sqlite files

Based on the [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26371494) (and [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877643/error-in-local-storage-ns-error-file-corrupted-firefox#comment75303180_26371494) from TheConstructor), here is what you can do in terminal:

1. Go to `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/`
2. `ls -al` and then `cd` into the folder that's touched recently. (If you have a Mozilla account to sync bookmarks and password with your phone, you are NOT on default.)
3. Run `for i in $(find . -name '*.sqlite'); do echo "$i"; echo "PRAGMA integrity_check;" | sqlite3 -bail "$i" 2>&1; done | grep -v ok | grep -v locked` and look for any output that's not a `./xxx/yyy.sqlite`.  (e.g. `Main freelist: size is 0 but should be 4`.) The file above the error is the corrupted file.
4. Move corrupted file(s) away. (either `rm` them, or `mv` somewhere else.)
5. Restart Firefox.  (I have a bookmark to `about:restartrequired` which is handy.)

It should hopefully fix the issue with minimal damage.

---

### Solution 3: Clear Profile Folder (and then Restore your Profile)

If solution 2 doesn't work, you have to clear the entire local data for the profile.

It was crucial for me not to lose my bookmarks and passwords in Firefox.

Here is what finally worked for me:

1. Make sure you create an account in Mozilla/Firefox and turn on Syncing. (top right button.)
   Optional: It's helpful to install Firefox on your phone and sync to make sure you have a live backup of your data and you are not losing passwords and bookmarks if things go wrong.
2. Open Finder. Go to `~/Library/Application Support`.  Move `Firefox` folder to trash.
3. Restart Firefox. (I have a bookmark for `about:restartrequired` that comes handy.)
4. Relogin to your profile in Firefox and sync.

#### Caveats

1. Your bookmarks are going to be out of order in the bookmark bar, and their icons are going to be blank until your first visit.
2. You have to login to every account (e.g. GMails) manually and one by one.  It should be straightforward if you have the passwords saved.

Comment: Been searching a long time for a solution of this error (in my case: heise.de did not show any images). The corrupt sqlite DB was the "ls-archive.sqlite": Export/import into new DB did not work. Since it is located at root of storage folder I deleted the whole folder - and now the error is gone. I had to enter some plugin/webiste logins data - but that's not much effort in comparison to the annoying behaviour before.

Answer (score 2):

So when I had this issue I went though the suggestions in the answers and they did not really help. Note that it was crucial to me to not lose history and preferable to not have to re-login on every site

**What did help was nuking the whole `storage` directory inside Firefox profile**

UPD: I lost add on configurations this way

What did not work:

- removing `webappsstore.sqlite` in Firefox profile directory
- removing `storage.sqlite`
- checking sqlite files using a script mentioned in one of the answers, it returned `ok` for all the files
- removing sqlite files for specific website that was broken (inside `storage` directory)

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem just pop up with one of our clients.

Completely deleting the `history` and (I guess that is the important part) `offline website data` solved the problem.

(Firefox Version **40.0.3**)

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Firefox 97 (2022). Deleting webappsstore.sqlite and storage.sqlite didn't resolve the issue, nor did deleting [Profile]/storage/default. YMMV.

What did however resolve this issue is:

- Settings -> Privacy & Security -> History
- Clear History...
- Time Range: Everything
- Under "History," only select: Cache
- Under "Data," only select: Site Settings and Offline Website Data under

And then reload the website(s) that are failing, and they should now be working. Only cost is losing site-specific settings.

Answer (score 1):

In your profile folder, use a sqlite database client to delete rows in `storage/ls-archive.sqlite`, where the key is the reverse ordered string of your problematic domain name. You might also need to remove `storage/default/<your-problematic-domain-name>` folders. This way you don't need to remove all your local storage in your profile.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but I have this issue on Jira. I restarted Firefox with addons disabled and wen to Jira and it worked. Then I stopped Firefox and restarted it with Addons enabled and it worked again. I don't know why this worked :) I use Firefox Developer edition 48.0a2 (2016-05-24)

Comment: Jira issue here too on FF50.0.1. Blank screens and unable to select the project. Deleted offline cache under Settings->Advanced->Network->Buffered Webcontent->Erase now *and* restarted Firefox.