# IO Error when using localStorage on Firefox 29+?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, local-storage

I am using localStorage in a very basic manner in an internal application. Its only storing a simple string value "newest" or "oldest":

```
localStorage.setItem('sortOrder', val)
```

But for some reason, certain users are throwing the following errors in Firefox:

```
Component returned failure code: 0x80630002 (NS_ERROR_STORAGE_IOERR) [nsIDOMStorage.getItem]

Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMStorage.getItem]
```

The IOERR occurs roughly 125 times a day across hundreds of page loads and FAILURE occurs only 5 or so times.

I found https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=700841, but none of our users have *any* extensions installed.

Google doesn't return anything particularly useful other than this wrapper around localStorage: https://github.com/doochik/SafeLS

I'm hesitant to silently catch all errors, but without anymore information, it sounds like the only solution...

Does anyone have any insight into what these errors actually mean? Any ideas what could cause localStorage to throw these errors?

Comment: Maybe a ' is missing after sortOrder: `localStorage.setItem('sortOrder', val)`

Comment: Just a typo on my part, thats not a copy/paste. I'll correct it.

Comment: I don't believe there are appropriate workarounds that reside outside of "try/catch". I use sessionStorage across pages that have 100's thousands users a day, and haven't run across any of those errors in my logs. Basically, I wrap my test for storage around try catch's, else use cookies. On different browsers - you can run into issues... when cookies are disabled AND you are using storage or when running in private mode etc...

Comment: `NS_ERROR_STORAGE_IOERR` really is just [`SQLITE_IOERR`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/48eee276b1ee/storage/src/mozStoragePrivateHelpers.cpp#l57), so this sounds like one or more of your users has a corrupt file system, full file system or corrupt, access-denied or locked [webappstore.sqlite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#Storage_location_and_clearing_the_data).

Comment: I've got the same error with a local MediaWiki installation. Deleting webappstore.sqlite in Firefox profile folder and therefore letting Firefox forcefully rebuilding it fixed the problem for me. Please see my extended answer over at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26371494/1696030

Answer (score 0):

**Override automatic cache management** was the culprit for me on Firefox 48 under:

- Edit
- Preferences
- Advanced

I selected that option in the hope that it would reduce the cache disk usage, as it enables the "Limit cache to X MB" dialog.

It did, but it also broke several websites in the process...