# phpMyAdmin displays a Javascript error at startup (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, phpmyadmin, macos-catalina

After a change of computer, from MacOS 10.14 to 10.15, PMA displays an error at startup, and the side navigation panel is unusable (all its links and buttons have no effect). With the same configuration, Safari works perfectly.
Below is the error report. All versions used (macOS, phpMyAdmin, MySQL, Firefox) are the latest versions.
Which file causes this NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED error?

```
{
    "pma_version": "4.9.2",
    "browser_name": "FIREFOX",
    "browser_version": "71.0",
    "user_os": "Mac",
    "server_software": "Apache/2.4.41 (Unix) PHP/7.3.9",
    "user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0",
    "locale": "fr",
    "configuration_storage": "enabled",
    "php_version": "7.3.9",
    "script_name": "index.php",
    "exception_type": "js",
    "exception": {
        "mode": "stack",
        "name": "NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED",
        "message": "",
        "stack": [
            {
                "func": "configGet",
                "line": "5131",
                "column": "30",
                "context": [
                    " *",
                    " * @return {object}                 Configuration value.",
                    " */",
                    "function configGet (key, cached) {",
                    "    cached = (typeof cached !== 'undefined') ? cached : true;",
                    "    var value = localStorage.getItem(key);",
                    "    if (cached && value !== undefined && value !== null) {",
                    "        return JSON.parse(value);",
                    "    }",
                    "",
                    "    // Result not found in local storage or ignored."
                ],
                "uri": "js/functions.js?v=4.9.2",
                "scriptname": "js/functions.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "initialize",
                "line": "63",
                "column": "30",
                "context": [
                    "    initialize: function () {",
                    "        if ($('#pma_console').length === 0) {",
                    "            return;",
                    "        }",
                    "",
                    "        PMA_console.config = configGet('Console', false);",
                    "",
                    "        PMA_console.isEnabled = true;",
                    "",
                    "        // Vars init",
                    "        PMA_console.$consoleToolbar = $('#pma_console').find('>.toolbar');"
                ],
                "uri": "js/console.js?v=4.9.2",
                "scriptname": "js/console.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "?",
                "line": "1494",
                "column": "17",
                "context": [
                    "",
                    "/** s",
                    " * Executed on page load",
                    " */",
                    "$(function () {",
                    "    PMA_console.initialize();",
                    "});",
                    ""
                ],
                "uri": "js/console.js?v=4.9.2",
                "scriptname": "js/console.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "e",
                "line": "2",
                "column": "29453",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v3.4.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/l//...",
                    "!function(e,t){\"use strict\";\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof modul//...",
                    ""
                ],
                "uri": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=4.9.2",
                "scriptname": "js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "l/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.

The problem came from the corrupted Firefox database. I removed /Users/[session]]/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/[random].default/webappsstore.sqlite

See [Error in local storage - NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED - firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877643/error-in-local-storage-ns-error-file-corrupted-firefox)